# Find the number of orthogonal matrices of order $2\times 2$ whose entries are $0,1$

Tags: matrices

Is there some method to solve these type of questions, or do I have to manually try out every possible matrix and check if it’s orthogonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the matrix have its elements $a_{11}=a,a_{12}=b,a_{21}=c,a_{22}=d $

Now easy to see $ad,bc\in${$0,1$},

As it is orthogonal $ad-bc=\pm 1$ if $ad-bc=1$ then $ad=1,bc=0$ (how many cases?) else $ad-bc=-1$  then $ad=0,bc=1$ (how many cases?)

Comment: Is $-1$ included? I think it’s only $ad-bc=1$

Comment: @Aditya determiant can be either 1 or -1

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Each row or column of an orthogonal matrix is a unit vector. If the matrix's entries are zeroes and ones, how many ones are there on each row or each column?